# How to add resizing for top and left in angular material

Tags: angular, material-ui, angular-material

I know how to resize right and bottom using this example.
But I am sruggling to add resizing for top and left
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vyjwfy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
Thanks in advance!